# Converting Windows batch to Linux script (Batch create symbolic links by first character)

Tags: linux, windows, script, batch, symbolic-link

As a noob to Linux and scripting I'm unsure as to how to convert this into a linux script or even where to start.
Essentially I want to create a script that creates alphabetized folders A-Z, symlink all folders in a directory to a the newly created sorted A-Z Directory so movies starting with A like Appleseed would be under the A folder.
*note I tried just running this bat in wine but mklink doesn't exist and wouldn't work so well.

```
::Make folders with each letter of the alphabet under the "categorized" folder if not already created
For %%M in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (mkdir "C:\My Videos\Categorized\"%%M)
::Does a directory search matching every letter A-Z and creates a output file listing each folder beginning with that letter 
For %%N in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do ((Dir "G:\My Videos\Movies\"%%N* /b) >> "C:\My Videos\List\%%N.lst") 
::Uses the previously created files to create symlinks of each line in the listed files into the alphabatized folders each A-Z folders
For %%O in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (For /F "usebackq delims==" %%P in ("C:\My Videos\List\%%O.lst") do (mklink /d  "G:\My Videos\Categorized\%%O\%%P" "G:\My Videos\Movies\%%P"))
```

Comment: “I'm unsure … where to start.”  Start by typing `man bash`.  Proceed to writing simple scripts.  Translate your batch file to a shell script one command at a time.

Comment: can you please help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403772/how-to-use-reuse-softlinks-created-on-mac-in-windows-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go.  The syntax is surprisingly very similar.  I shortened the listing of the alphabet with .. but you could list it out if you want and it would still work.  I'm not sure if your *nix box is going to be happy about those file paths though.

```
#Make folders with each letter of the alphabet under the "categorized" folder if not already created
for M in {A..Z}; do mkdir "C:\My Videos\Categorized\${M}"; done;
#Does a directory search matching every letter A-Z and creates a output file listing each folder beginning with that letter 
for N in {A..Z}; do ls "G:\My Videos\Movies\${N}"* >> "C:\My Videos\List\${N}.lst"; done;
#Uses the previously created files to create symlinks of each line in the listed files into the alphabatized folders each A-Z folders
for O in {A..Z}; do for P in $(cat "C:\My Videos\List\${O}.lst"); do ln -s  "G:\My Videos\Categorized\${O}\${P}" "G:\My Videos\Movies\${P}"; done; done;
#This alternate version for the last line correctly deals with whitespace in your filenames
for O in {A..Z}; do 
    while read P; do 
        ln -s  "G:\My Videos\Categorized\${O}\${P}" "G:\My Videos\Movies\${P}";
    done < "C:\My Videos\List\${O}.lst";
done;
```

Comment: The last part doesn't seem to work for me I'm using Ubuntu mint flavor 14 nadia. Specifically the symlink is pinking up whitespace in the /media/Movies/My Videos/List/A.lst file I'm using this line 
    for O in A; do for P in $(cat "/media/Movies/My Videos/List/$O.lst"); do ln -s "/media/Movies/My Videos/Movies/${P}" "/media/Movies/My Videos/Categorized/${O}/${P}"; done; done;
 this is the result 
    ln: failed to create symbolic link `/media/Movies/My Videos/Categorized/A/The': File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link `/media/Movies/My Videos/Categorized/A/[2011]"': File exists

Comment: Didn't realize you have whitespace in your filenames. Use this: `for O in {A..Z}; do 
 while read P; do 
  ln -s  "G:\My Videos\Categorized\${O}\${P}" "G:\My Videos\Movies\${P}";
 done < "C:\My Videos\List\${O}.lst";
done;`

Comment: can you please have a look the link and help  me ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403772/how-to-use-reuse-softlinks-created-on-mac-in-windows-8